# Why specify lifetime for valued stored struct storing a reference in Rust?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm new to Rust and I don't understand why you need to indicate the life time of the `Outer` struct in the following code snippet.

The following code does not compile (Error: missing lifetime specifier
expected named lifetime parameter):

```
    struct Inner<'a> {
        i: &'a i32
    }

    struct Outer {
        inner: Inner 
    }
```

The following code does compile as expected:

```
    struct Inner<'a> {
        i: &'a i32
    }

    struct Outer<'a> {
        inner: Inner<'a> 
    }
```

I don't get why in this case you need to specify the lifetime of `Inner` as it is stored as a value in `Outer`. Shouldn't it be sufficient to know that `inner` will live as long as any instance of `Outer` (as it belongs to `Outer`) and that `i` live as long as any instance of `Inner`? Why cannot we then infer that the reference `i` will live as long as any instance of `Outer`?

Comment: It can't be shorter than that (and indeed, there is such implied bound), but it can be longer, and you may need to use that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, I'm confused. What do you mean by "it can be longer, and you may need to use that"?

Comment: What don't you understand in that statement?

Comment: What "can be longer" and concerning "you may need to use that", does it refers to the lifetime specifier?

Comment: There's no guarantee here that `i` will live longer than your `Outer` instance. You could trivially construct this as `let i = 0; let outer = Box::new(Outer { inner: &i });` and then return `outer` which references something that does not live long enough. This is where `Rc` or `Arc` comes into play.

Comment: Ok, I see, it makes a lot more sens now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Suppose you store a `'static` reference inside. You may want to use it as `'static`, even after the struct is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't get why in this case you need to specify the lifetime of `Inner`

I think this is suggesting a misunderstanding of the difference between `&'a Foo` and `Foo<'a>`

The first, `&'a Foo`, is a borrowed reference to a `Foo` that is owned by something else with a lifetime of (at least) `'a`.

The second, `Foo<'a>`, is an owned type that is only valid for the lifetime `'a` for some reason - usually because it holds a reference that is borrowed for that lifetime or (like in your case) another type that is only valid for that lifetime.

Imagine that your first snippet was valid. If the value that the inner was referencing goes out of scope, there's nothing saying the the `Outer` value is no longer valid even though it (indirectly) references a dropped value and this is therefore not allowed.